# Upload Shapefile to PostGis

Tags: python-3.x, shapefile

I have a shapefile and I dont know how I can upload it to my PostGis with Python 3.

Does anyone have an example or idea of ​​how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could execute `shp2pgslq` command using `subprocess` to obtain the sql query for postgis.

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(["shp2pgsql", "layer.shp", "schemaName.tableName"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output, err = p.communicate()
```

Then you can use the `output` query with your database.

https://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#shp2pgsql_usage
https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/subprocess.html

Hope it helps.